# Phpunit test is passing when ran via xdebug while debugging but fails when run in normal way

Tags: php, phpunit

I wrote some test cases using Phpunit.

When i execute them in the console one of the tests failed.
So i used xdebug with phpstorm on the cli.The code executed correctly and the test passed.There were no code changes.I stepped thorough thoroughly and the code seem to have no errors.

Anyone experienced a similar issue if so what was the solution.

```
public function testGetAccruedDaysFromProcessDateBeginning() {
    $annualLeaveType = $this->getLeaveTypeService()->readLeaveType(1);
    $leaveTypeRule = $this->getLeaveTypeRuleService()->readLeaveTypeRule($annualLeaveType);
    $leaveEntitlementRule = $leaveTypeRule->getLeaveEntitlementRule();
    $employee = $this->getEmployeeService()->getEmployee(1);
    $accruedDaysCount = $this->getLeaveEntitlementProcessor()->getAccruedDaysFromProcessDate($employee, $leaveEntitlementRule, '2015-01-01');
    $this->assertEquals(15, $accruedDaysCount);
}


public function testGetAccruedDaysFromProcessDateEnd() {
    $annualLeaveType = $this->getLeaveTypeService()->readLeaveType(1);
    $leaveTypeRule = $this->getLeaveTypeRuleService()->readLeaveTypeRule($annualLeaveType);
    $leaveEntitlementRule = $leaveTypeRule->getLeaveEntitlementRule();
    $employee = $this->getEmployeeService()->getEmployee(1);
    $accruedDaysCount = $this->getLeaveEntitlementProcessor()->getAccruedDaysFromProcessDate($employee, $leaveEntitlementRule, '2015-12-31');
    $this->assertEquals(16, $accruedDaysCount);
}
```

Comment: Please provide source code of your failing test.

Comment: the first one is passing but the second one is failing only when ran on cli , works fine on debug mode

Comment: At which point is it failing? What was the actual result?

Comment: the actual result returned is 15 for second one,16 is returned if ran on xdebug so the second test pass.

Comment: (using telepathy because there's not enough information) Tests failing in one environment and passing in another usually mean bad isolation: either global state leaks between tests and makes them depend on a particular order they're run in; or execution environment influences tests. Are PHP/PHPUnit versions the same in both cases? Do autoloads work the same way? Is PHPUnit config getting loaded properly? Are you running them on the same machine?

Comment: sorry for the little amount of code i shared this is using multiple service classes and that results in about 6 or 7 large classes.which make sharing difficult. Both tests are running on the same environment

Comment: ps.The underlying system is using symfony 1.4 framework. if that helps.

Comment: i changed the order of the calls and tested.the test still fails for the assertEqual 16